# Show that $\sum_k \sin (\pi/k)$ diverges

Tags: real-analysis

I tried by evaluating the limits but they both go to 0. What is the right way to go about this?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Since $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\sin x}{x} = 1$, you have $\displaystyle\lim_{k \to \infty}\dfrac{\sin \frac{\pi}{k}}{\frac{1}{k}} = \pi$.

So you can use the limit comparison theorem to compare the given sum to $\displaystyle\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{k}$